# Listing files from Google Drive api results in a system formatexception

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using the Google .net client library to request data from the Google Drive API I am getting an exception on the following line.

```
FileList files = request.Execute();
```

[image]

**My full code:**

```
public List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> retrieveAllFiles()
    {
        DriveService service = GetDriveService();
        List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> result = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();

        do
        {

                FileList files = request.Execute();

                result.AddRange(files.Files);
                request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;

        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
        return result;
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand what could be causing this problem

Comment: would you mind posting your code for GetDriveService(); ?  This is either an issue with the drive api or the client library.   I just tested it with my version of GetdriveService and its working.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your ApplicationName is invalid. You are using non English letters there.

If you can confirm that this is the issue, I'll create a bug in our tracker (https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues) to follow this one.